# Which asp.net technology fits this situation best?

Tags: web-development, asp.net-mvc, websites, webforms

I think I can count WebAPI out, but WebForms, WebPages, and MVC are all possibilities.

I want to create an asp.net web site that is primarily static content and links to other sites. The only "fancy" bit will be a Bing map with pushpins that I add - but even these are static. And there will be a photo gallery. Oh, and ads, too.

And, finally, it needs to work well on phones and tablets as well as desktop browsers.

Which asp.net technology "flavor" is most suited for this type of web site?

### UPDATE

In VS 2012, Web Pages projects are not available beneath Templates | Visual C# | Web.

What *is* there:

```
ASP.NET Empy Web Application
ASP.NET Web Forms Application
ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application
ASP.NET MVC 4 WebApplication
ASP.NET Dyanmic Data Entities Web Application
```

Does this mean that Web Pages are passe, or that Web Pages and Web Forms are the same thing?

Comment: Whichever one you are most experienced and comfortable with. They can all handle those simple requirements easily.

Comment: How much content? 10 pages? 100? 1000 or more? How often will elements (header, footer, content, ads) on pages change, rarely or frequently?

Comment: Closest to 100. Elements will change rarely, except for ads, which will presumably change based on some algorithm or so the adsuppliers provide.

Comment: FYI, Web Pages and Web Forms are the same thing.

Comment: Based on what it says at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/aspnet/?WT.mc_id=A5A71FF5F, namely:

"Create web sites using ASP.NET MVC, Web Forms, or Web Pages."

...I don't think Web Forms and Web Pages are quite the same thing. I don't know just how they differ, though...

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to discard WebForms because you're not accepting user data, no MVC because, well, your model isn't going to be substantial. That leaves WebPages.

But let's look at this from another perspective: what happens when the requirements change? Are you looking forward to doing much of what you've already done over again because your site needs added functionality, because suddenly there IS supposed to be heavy user interaction, data being pushed back to the server, a model that will influence your view?

Don't be too quick to choose the easy way out because more often than not, that means closing the door on flexibility and scalability. More often than not, at some point, sailor-like swearing will ensue.

Go with MVC. We don't live in an era of a static web anymore.

As far as multi-device goes: that's mainly a CSS-related endeavor, should have very little to do with ASP.NET in itself. If you design it well from the start, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider something like [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/), it's lightweight and aims to get out of your way as much as possible. As @Wim Ombelets says you really don't need the overhead of WebForms and both the Model and Controllers are probably also more than you'll require which means you *probably* wont need the MVC framework either.